# SQL query to multiply with earlier records factor

Tags: sql, t-sql

[image]

I'm trying to select a record by ID, they all have the same base value, but different multipliers.
so i want the base value multiplied by whatever comes next like given image shows

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    a.value * ( 1 + SUM(a.multiplier) OVER(
        PARTITION BY id
    ) / 100 ) desired_column
FROM
    aux a;
```

Output

```
ID  VALUE   MULTIPLIER  DESIRED_COLUMN
1     120            2             126
1     120            3             126
2     110            4           123.2
2     110            8           123.2
```

If you want just one row per id, then go with this:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.value * ( 1 + SUM(a.multiplier) / 100 ) desired_column
FROM
    aux a
GROUP BY
    a.id,
    a.value;
```

Output

```
ID  DESIRED_COLUMN
1              126
2            123.2
```

Comment: It seems that `from dual` has trouble finding `dual`. And using integer arithmetic to calculate percentages doesn't produce the OP's desired results. Perhaps you could provide a working [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) and an _explanation_ of your answer.

Comment: @HABO Sorry, I hadn't realised dual didnt't exist in tsql. Why aren't the expected results being produced?

Comment: You calculate something like `select 120 * 2 / 100;` while the OP is thinking more along the lines of `select 120 * 1.02;` (or `select 120 * ( 1 + 2 / 100.0 );`).

Comment: ¨@HABO Could the question please be edited showing desired output?

Comment: I thought that the pixels that vaguely resemble `select 120 * 1.02 + ( ( 120 * 1.03 ) - 120 ); -- Should then be 126.` would indicate that `select 120 * ( 1 + ( 2 + 3 ) / 100 );` doesn't meet the OP's needs since it returns `120`. The question can, and should, be edited for a variety of reasons.

Comment: [What your code does](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c93d809798c31e6035af6f1293684e0f). I'm done.

Comment: This does exactly what i needed !
any chance @jeiv that you could tell me how i only get the desired column once ?
so it would show me the summed value just one time without all multipliers,etc. so basically how to just output/select the last multiplied value pr. Id ?
ID      Desired_Column
1                 126
2                 123.2

Comment: @robskaar Glad to hear that. So you're then using Oracle as DBMS?

Comment: @jeiv Actually MSSQL, but this does work for me

Comment: @robskaar please find an edit in my answer showing how to just show one value per id.

Comment: @HABO it seems this is working for MSSQL? Not sure why the fiddle was not.

Comment: @jeiv the edit for single record selection worked perfectly ! thank you so much, this really solved an issue for me, i've been around something just like it but whatever i did i kept getting values that were just off by a little or each id's value with the multiplier so i had to deduct the value from each result... Marking it as an answer, thanks again ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for arithmetic?

```
select t.*, (value * (1.0 + multiplier / 100.0)) as calculated_value
from t;
```